# Open multiple files at once by QGIS actions buttons

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, actions

I'm planning to put into my table a column with folder path, so it will be easy to open a folder with needed files in attributes table. Now I'm wondering if I could open not the folder, but all files in it.

It would be great to just get all pdf in directory, no matter how they are named (so I don't have to store filenames anywhere). But the schema is simple: all files have prefix and number from _1 to _7, eg. a_1.pdf, a_2.pdf, a_3.pdf... But sometimes one of those files is missing.

I tried to put all paths to varchar, as string like "C:\a_1.pdf;C:\a_2.pdf(...)" or as array but "open" doesn't work with more than one path. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define a action type "Python" and then use a little python script to open multiple PDFs at once. In this example I have an attribute named 'path' which holds the path information. Be aware that the backslash in the path information in Python must be escaped or use a normal slash (must be c:/test/ or with double backslashes). so the whole thing looks like this:

[image]

and the code should be like this:

```
import os
dir = '[%path%]'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
   for fname in files:
       os.startfile(dir+fname)
```

I only tested it with QGIS (3.4) for windows.

Comment: Yeah, it works. I looked at other topics and ended with something like this
`import os
dir = str(r'[%path%]').replace('\\','\\\\')
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
   for fname in files:
       os.startfile(dir+"\\\\"+fname)`
so I can use my column with standard path.
Thank you!